# google-apps-script Changing column format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

need to format columns c, e and a few others to show the date using the format below:

4 July 2014

Can't work out how to do it ... new to google script!

Answer (score 13):

To do this using Apps script, you can use the [setNumberFormat(numberFormat)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range), which lists that date formats follow the [SimpleDateFormat specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Sample code that will do this:

```
function formatDate(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange("A2").setNumberFormat('dd MMM yyyy');
};
```