# Automatically change format of a column in multiple tabs of one Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would love to be able to automatically change a format of one column in my google spreadsheet doc. I'm using teradata to get info to the doc, it refreshes daily. The problem I have is that one column is in number format like:
0.1234 and I would love to have it changed automatically for multiple tabs (but same column) after it refresh to percentage so it's in a format: 12.34%. When I do it manually the next time the data refreshes it's again in an automatic format.

Is this doable with a google script?

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you explain precisely how you are using teradata?

Comment: Are you importing / updating the data with a sheet formula like =IMPORTRANGE or similar?

Comment: You're asking two questions. 1) _Is it possible to adjust the column format with a script._ The answer to that is probably (I hesitate to say "yes" without more information about your scenario). 2) _How do I do this?_ StackOverflow is not a code writing service, and you are expected to do a reasonable amount of research before posting your question. This question should help you [google-apps-script Changing column format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27589578/1330560)

Comment: @Cooper I've got a SQL query that export data to a Google Spreadsheet, precisely to 4 different tabs in the same spreadsheet. Data looks exactly the same column-wise just different criteria per tab. One of the column shows data as 0.1234, and would love it to format the data automatically to 12.34%. As I explained above that after every refresh of data (once daily) it comes back to 0.1234 format even when I put percentage format in there (kind of weird because financial data stay with good $ format even when the data refreshes).

Comment: @Tedinoz I tried modifying the script and several others, but I couldn't make this work for a) multiple tabs and b) with percentage format.

Comment: It is doing with an `onChange` trigger that would run a format modifying function each time new data comes in. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59362734/on-edit-doesnt-work-if-cell-auto-updates-need-a-workaround-google-sheets/59370962#59370962) to get the idea.